# Error when assigning SSL binding in Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, ssl

I'm trying to configure SSL for my ASP.NET MVC web app in Azure. I succesfully uploaded the certificate in the portal, but when I try to assing my website to the certificate, I get an error that there is no endpoint listening.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by repairing my SSL certificate.